# apache Digester: Unexspected NoSuchMethodException on addSetNestedProperties

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I have a problem using Digester and I hope you can help me. I have the following Bean:

```
public class MyEntry {
   private String entityID;

   public String getEntityID() { return this.entityID; }
   public void setEntityID(final String entityID) { this.entityID = entityID; }
}
```

And the following XML structure:

```
<entries>
  <entry>
     <MyID>
        24309LAGH1
     </MyID>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

I use the addSetNestedProperties(…) method of the digester API:

```
digester.addSetNestedProperties("entries/entry", "MyID", "entryID");
```

The following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Bean has no property named MyID
```

Why is digester searching for a property named “MyID”? I specified “entryID” as bean property accorsing to the digester API

Thanks :)

Best regards
QStorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[original]

You do not use the correct rule to perform your task.

Try using this instead:

```
digester.addBeanPropertySetter("entries/entry/MyID", "entityID");
```

Tips: activate the log4j in your main by using for instance `BasicConfigurator.configure();`. The output can be very useful.

[edit]

If you want to use `addSetNestedProperties`:

```
public class MyEntry {
   private String entityID;

   public String getEntityID() { return this.entityID; }
   public void setEntityID(final String entityID) { this.entityID = entityID; }
}
```

and for `new Digester().parse(myFile)`;

```
digester.addObjectCreate("entries/entry", MyEntry.class);
digester.addSetNestedProperties("entries/entry", "MyID", "entityID");
//your propertyName was not the same as in your Bean Class Fields.
```

and I presume that your Exception was:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Bean has no property named entryID
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the name of getters and setters like are uppercase or lowercase of your property "entityID. Probably your getter name is like this --> "getEntityID" try to change for this --> "getentityID"

**Edit**

Sorry, the property you have to check is --> "MyID"